# Remove element.field from ArrayNode

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have such json ArrayNode and I need to remove from each element for example field **"xxx"** using ObjectMapper, ArrayNode, JsonNode or ObjectNode. **But without Gson and @JsonIgnore etc.**

```
"arrayNode": [
               {
                 "xxx": {},
                 "yyy": {}
               },
               {
                 "xxx": {},
                 "yyy": {}
               }
             ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this problem has been solved or not. But following code snippet shows how to remove a field whose key is `xxx` from JSON node. And a `JsonNode` cannot perform insertion or deletion, so you have to cast it to `ObjectNode` for further manipulation.

**Code snippet**

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonStr);
 rootNode.get("arrayNode").forEach(e -> {
     if (e.has("xxx")) {
         ObjectNode objNode = (ObjectNode) e;
         objNode.remove("xxx");
     }
 });

 System.out.println(rootNode.toString());
```

**Console output**

> {"arrayNode":[{"yyy":{}},{"yyy":{}}]}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this maven dependency : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160212

It's very simple to understated and use. ex:

```
JSONObject obj = "YOUR_JSON_STRING";
JSONArray result = obj.getJSONArray("YOUR_STRING_KEY");

for(JSONObject elem : result){
   String out = elem.getString("xxx");
}
```

More you can read at : https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html
Good luck

Comment: I suppose that it would be helpful, but I'm not able to use any libs except Jackson

Comment: answer doesn't say anything about removal